# Is it correct to say "How many more sets do you have?" at the gym?

Tags: idioms, american-english, phrases

Is it correct to say "How many more sets do you have?" at the gym?

I think what I heard from native speakers was something like: "How many more sets you got to do?"

Comment: Hello Goodman,  I'll remove the second and third questions that are unrelated.  It's best to keep a question focused on a single topic.  Also, don't use the ` for quotes.  It makes the system format the words for computer programs in a fixed font.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing ungrammatical about "How many more sets do you have?", but it sounds a little odd.  You don't "have" sets that are in the future. It is far more idiomatic to ask "How many more sets have you got to do?".  That asks about future obligation (the obligation because you "have to do sets" to reach your target). In casual speech the word "have" might be dropped.

Comment: Is it also odd to say `How many more sets you have to do?`

Comment: In standard English "How many more sets do you have to do?"  But the "do" might be deleted in very casual settings (such as someone speaking when out of breath at a gym).

Comment: This might be a US/UK split.  In US English, "How many more sets do you have" (meaning "...do you have to do") sounds normal and unremarkable.

Answer (score -1):

I think the phrase you are looking for is

> How many sets do you do at the gym.